# Can $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] be injected?

Tags: php

I am running a PHP website using Apache+mod_fastcgi.
There is an error in Apache error log:

```
malformed header from script 'ajax.php': Bad header: /;ls -la HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Requ
```

Here is the only piece of code in ajax.php that sends the header:

```
if(!isset($_POST['action'])) {
    header ($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 400 Bad Request');
    exit;
}
```

So where did `/;ls -la` piece come from? Can SERVER_PROTOCOL be injected in any way?

Comment: This `ls -la` seems to be the Unix command to list files and directories. What is your `ajax.php` file content?

Comment: Related: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32299/is-server-a-safe-source-of-data-in-php

Comment: Something is definitely wrong here.  My understanding is that `'SERVER_PROTOCOL'` has a fixed set of valid values and that the web server itself should error if that's not the case.  Is there a mod_rewrite altering this?

Comment: @DimasPante, http://pastebin.com/ibEqCwnr. Nothing special. Required files do not mess with $_SERVER, and it would be strange if they did

Comment: @BaconBits, mod_rewrite is enable and doing its things as well, but the error clearly says that the malformed header comes from the script.

Comment: Try to offer some debugging info. Maybe do a `print_r` on $_SERVER and see if there are other wrong values. Check the protocol in the request and response headers for `ajax.php` using a developer console such as Firebug. Make sure you're not doing other output before calling `header()` or other `header()` calls in the included files.

Comment: I understand, but I am unable to repeat it.

Comment: some bot sends wrong http-headers as a test for vulnerabilities. Search for the apache exploits.

Answer (score 1):

> There are two special-case header calls. The first is a header that 
>   starts with the string "HTTP/" (case is not significant), which will be 
>   used to figure out the HTTP status code to send. (from [PHP header documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php))

The correct (and secure) way to send a status code as above therefore is:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request');
```

Whether you use `HTTP/1.0` or `HTTP/1.1` is not important.